# Linux on mobile phone?

Tags: linux, phone

How to install Linux on mobile phone natively, not through Bochs, QEMU or Deploy Linux/Complete Linux Install? Are there any nuances here and which ones?

EDIT: I mean Desktop version for ARM(maybe Ubuntu MATE). Can it be installed to phone/tablet?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Which mobile phone are you considering? There may be substantial differences based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- KDE Plasma https://www.plasma-mobile.org/get : only compatible with Nexus 5X.
- Ubuntu Touch: https://ubports.com
- SailFish OS: https://sailfishos.org

Comment: I don't know the OP's expectations, but Nexus 5X is a 2015 discontinued phone and SailFish OS includes closed source, something many Linux users are allergic to. I don't know how well ubports is managing the project, but the originator, Canonical abandoned it for lack of users. Maybe the answer is simply that the only mature OS for smartphone are Android and Apple's. The truth is that modern phone hardware has too many proprietary stuff. It's difficult to deal with that.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I absolutely agree with you. What's more Linux/GNU is simply not well-suited for mobile. I will never replace my Android with something which barely works, doesn't have any apps, has tons of bugs, and eats battery for breakfast.